# Is returning Eigen::Ref legit?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

Eigen's doc explain how `Eigen::Ref` can be used as function parameters. Is it a good idea to use it as function return values too?

For example

```
class XyTracker : public XyListener {
 public:
  XyTracker() = default;
  XyTracker(XyTracker&&) = default;
  XyTracker& operator=(XyTracker&&) = default;

  const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::ArrayXXd> Xs() const;
  const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::ArrayXd> Ys() const;

  // XyListener
  void OnXy(const Eigen::VectorXd& x, double y) final;

 private:
  Eigen::ArrayXXd xs_;
  Eigen::ArrayXd ys_;
  Eigen::Index n_ = 0;
};

inline const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::ArrayXXd> XyTracker::Xs() const {
  return xs_.topRows(n_);
}

inline const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::ArrayXd> XyTracker::Ys() const {
  return ys_.head(n_);
}
```

Comment: At the very least, you will have to take care of ensuring the lifetimes.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using Eigen::Ref as return type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was already noted in the comments, there is nothing wrong with returning `Ref` objects, as long as you make sure that the object you are referring to is still valid at the time you are using the reference.

Simplified example:

```
struct A {
    ArrayXXd xs;
    Ref<const ArrayXXd> Xs() const {
        return xs.topRows(5);  // works (when used properly)
    }
    Ref<const ArrayXXd> NotWorking() const {
        ArrayXXd foo = 2*xs;
        return foo.topRows(5); // compiles, but will give U.B.
};


// usage:
A a;
a.xs.setRandom(10,10);

Ref<const ArrayXXd> r1 = a.Xs();
// fine to use r1 here
a.xs.setRandom(20,20);
// from here on r1 will point to non-existing memory
// i.e., using r1 will be U.B.
```

The U.B. (undefined behavior) examples are all essentially use-after-free, which unfortunately are barely detected by compilers, so you need to be somewhat careful when working with `Eigen::Ref`. UB can mean that your unit-tests work, although your code is bad, but suddenly in production you'll get a seg-fault ...